# Digest::SHA2.hexdigest generates two completely different values from same parameters

Tags: ruby

This is one of the weirdest I've seen. There's some legacy code I'm maintaining that generates a digest:

```
require 'digest/sha1'
def encrypt(password, salt)
  Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("--#{salt}--#{password}--")
end
```

I call that method with "hello" and "world" as the parameters and I get this:

```
15ea8ac62708f3810b720b25dd6febe9d0ddc1ed
```

But if I do this directly:

```
Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("--world--hello--")
```

I get:

```
c95b3d8968d8044c42ff650ade81315ab9adf120e2b62a637e64fa362cb828dd
```

Excuse my french, but WTF?!

Is there some sort of setting for `Digest::SHA2` that I should be looking for? What could be triggering the disparity?

Comment: I just tried `Digest::SHA1.hexdigest` and it spits out the same as the `encrypt` method above... now the question is why!?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think your first code is actually:

```
def encrypt(password, salt)
  Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("--#{salt}--#{password}--")
end
```

...because:

```
irb> Digest::SHA1.hexdigest '--world--hello--'
#=> "15ea8ac62708f3810b720b25dd6febe9d0ddc1ed"
irb> Digest::SHA2.hexdigest '--world--hello--'
#=> "c95b3d8968d8044c42ff650ade81315ab9adf120e2b62a637e64fa362cb828dd"
```

So perhaps the code you put in your question is not the code that is actually in your application, or someone else is redefining `encrypt` the exact same way, but using SHA1, or you have made your changes in code but are still using old/cached code without realizing it.

Comment: Yep, I just searched all the code and sure enough, there's another not so obvious part where the method is redefined... Should've thought of that sooner. Thanks.