# Generate unique token from specific variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would you generate a unique token from a specific variable like a device id (string) to secure a rails api ?

I am looking for something like:

```
SecureRandom.hash_algo(deviceId)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a random token with this:

```
token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
```

EDIT:

```
require 'digest/sha1'
Digest::SHA1.hexdigest deviceId
```

Comment: it would be good if I wanted to generate a basic unique token but in my case I want the **device id** to be involved in the hash

Comment: So you don't want generate a unique token but a hash, so use hash method like SHA1, look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490/how-do-i-create-a-sha1-hash-in-ruby.

Comment: actually it's more like a random token hashed with the device id as salt

Comment: Ok but use the deviceId like a salt is useless. With a hash you always have the same result with a deviceId but if you use deviceId like a salt you will always have a different result...

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Something different for every token generation

Comment: In this case you don't need a salt, you just generate a random token.

Comment: Ok I see your point. I just have to keep a pair of the device id and its associated random token. No need to apply the device id to the token generation since in both case it will be random

Answer (score 1):

If the string must be a digest of an input, rather than a random string, you can use the `Digest` library to generate a hash. A few examples can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809012/digestsha2-hexdigest-generates-two-completely-different-values-from-same-param)

```
require 'digest/sha2'
Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(deviceId)
```

Otherwise, the [`SecureRandom`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) library has a bunch of methods to generate random strings.

**Hexadecimal string.**

```
p SecureRandom.hex(10) #=> "52750b30ffbc7de3b362"
p SecureRandom.hex(10) #=> "92b15d6c8dc4beb5f559"
p SecureRandom.hex(13) #=> "39b290146bea6ce975c37cfc23"
```

**Base64 string.**

```
p SecureRandom.base64(10) #=> "EcmTPZwWRAozdA=="
p SecureRandom.base64(10) #=> "KO1nIU+p9DKxGg=="
p SecureRandom.base64(12) #=> "7kJSM/MzBJI+75j8"
```

**Binary string.**

```
p SecureRandom.random_bytes(10) #=> "\016\t{\370g\310pbr\301"
p SecureRandom.random_bytes(10) #=> "\323U\030TO\234\357\020\a\337"
```